# Issue with running Tensorflow Object Detection train job on my own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am probably missing something obvious but after following the steps outlined in the [running locally](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) README, I can't successfully submit a train job in EC2 V100 instance.

So far, I completed the following steps:

#### Tensorflow version '1.13.1'

1. Converted the train and test to TFRecord format
2. Created a new label map pb.txt with the 6 classes for my dataset.
3. Updated the pipeline config [file](https://gist.github.com/domarps/56a455871b7db8d000cc2b4ef348e365) to reflect the paths and the number of classes.

My final directory structure is as follows (+ denotes folder and - denotes file):

```
+ models
 + faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28
   - model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
   - model.ckpt.meta
   - model.ckpt.index
 + model
    + train
    + eval
    - pipeline.config

+ data
 - train.record
 - test.record
 - tp_label_map.pbtxt
```

One concern is that I do not know what the train and eval folders inside the models correspond to in the README.

[image]

4. Populated the env variables and launched train job as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-training-job).

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config
MODEL_DIR=/home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/models/model
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50000
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=$SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES \
    --alsologtostderr
```

I get the following warnings and it just hangs there for 10 mins or so. Not moving to the train stage.

But I do get the files populated in the model directory (train and eval are empty).

```
+models
  - events.out.tfevents.1557175306.ip-172-31-32-179
  - graph.pbtxt 
  - model.ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001  
  - model.ckpt-0.index 
  - model.ckpt-0.meta
```

If you look up the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624915/3270315), but when I checked `nvidia-smi` or `tensorboard`, I dont see anything generated.

Tensorboard output

[image: Scalars Graphs]

```
WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

*********** In model lib ************* /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f6c5b26d048>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:80: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/utils/ops.py:472: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/inputs.py:320: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:152: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py:1624: flatten (from tensorflow.python.layers.core) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.flatten instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:2298: get_or_create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py:345: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:110: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py:785: to_int64 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py:429: py_func (from tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
tf.py_func is deprecated in TF V2. Instead, use
    tf.py_function, which takes a python function which manipulates tf eager
    tensors instead of numpy arrays. It's easy to convert a tf eager tensor to
    an ndarray (just call tensor.numpy()) but having access to eager tensors
    means `tf.py_function`s can use accelerators such as GPUs as well as
    being differentiable using a gradient tape.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py:1266: checkpoint_exists (from tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use standard file APIs to check for files with this prefix.
```

Comment: What's the error? There's only warnings...

Comment: what is the command you used to submit the job?

Comment: edited to add the issue and command to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation are indeed a bit unclear about `model_dir`, but the source code [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/a182abc1cffec2b9325300f1555d50d11b9360fb/research/object_detection/model_main.py#L28) has a clear explanation of it.

So `model_dir` is the directory where you would save your new checkpoint files to, **it is not the same as the pretrained checkpoint files which you used for fine-tuning** and you should not set `model_dir` to pretrained checkpoint path.

It is better to keep `model_dir` empty of checkpoint files each time you submit a new training job, otherwise if there are checkpoint files, the model would possibly skip training ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162628/estimators-model-fn-includes-params-argument-but-params-are-not-passed-to-esti)).

The `train` and `eval` directories are listed there for illustration. It can be an option to set the directory structure like that but not necessary to be the same. You just need to pass an empty directory to `model_dir` where the checkpoint files can be saved.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications. So, if I wanted to simply start training a model (say faster_rcnn pretrained on coco), will I be able use the weights of that model rather than having to train from scratch? In which case, how do I modify the `pipeline.config` file:

Comment: I saw in your pasted config file, your `fine_tune_checkpoint ` is already set correctly.

Comment: I've updated the status after following these points -- still no progress though.

Comment: Those files generated under `models` are checkpoint files. Evaluation will be performed around every 10 mins or more. `train` and `eval` are both OK to be empty. The thing is the directory structure is recommended but not a must. You just need to pass correct values when you submit the job.

Comment: when use tensorboard, set logdir to `models` and you can check if the loss decreases over steps

Comment: edited to add tensorboard graph. I can see the pbtxt file loaded, but the model is not training.

Comment: what is the size of your eval dataset, in the config file it is 8000. This number should be set according to your eval dataset size (the number of images.)

Comment: Updated the eval dataset size to 2800.

Comment: what about now? I saw two pipeline.config files in two different folders. Are they the same?

Comment: Nice catch, I moved the config file from the other folder to the models folder.