# How/where the checkpoint files are loaded

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am running model_main.py of tensorflow object_detection model.
I would like to know which .py file has the code, where the model checks for existing checkpoint in 'mode_dir' and how does the model know to load/start from the latest checkpoint saved.

I checked in model_lib.py, but unable to figure out yet.

Comment: `model_dir` is the path where checkpoint files are saved but not loaded. Probably you are referring to the checkpoint path for pretrained model?

Comment: Yes, when I ran for the first time, the checkpoint files are saved in model_dir. But when I run next time with more steps, I think it checks the mode_dir path for existing checkpoint files and save the first checkpoint(for 2nd run) based on the latest checkpoint file and then start training from where it left. If my first run was 100 steps and 2nd run is 300 steps, the 2nd run will start from 100 and not from 0. So, I would like to know how/where the 2nd run gets the information about already existing checkpoints and start from the latest.

Comment: That is not the way how tensorflow OD API keep training from checkpoint works. If `model_dir` is not empty, tensorflow will first check if those checkpoints saved have reached the number of training steps, if yes, the training would be skipped. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52201093/1621414.  But in your case, the number of training steps has not been reached (you set a bigger num_steps), in this case, the model would still start training from stratch. (I am not completely sure but in my experience with the API, i would see two training loss plots in tensorboard).

Comment: If you want to use the checkpoint saved in `model_dir`, you need to specify the `checkpoint: /path/to/checkpoint` in the config file under filed `train_config`.

Comment: In the model_dir, a file named as `checkpoint` was generated and updated each time a new checkpoint was saved, contains the most recent filename of the checkpoint. I presume that this file is read each time you attempt to resume the training.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the discussion above, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d44b7283cbf27d7b68153fda00058c76e7ccd064/research/object_detection/model_lib.py#L332) is where the pretrained checkpoints are loaded in tensorflow object detection api. As you can see, the checkpoint paths are passed by the variable `train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint`, this variable is a field under `train_config` in the config file. It is not the same as `model_dir`, which is only used for saving the most recent checkpoints.

If you use the same command line to resume training, the training seemed to automatically start from the latest checkpoint in `model_dir` and this is supported by tensorflow Supervisor. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4116#issuecomment-387105242) for reference.

Comment: I have already checked this place. I put some debug statement to see if there is any information about existing checkpoint files here, but there is none.

Comment: Can you also share your config file?

Comment: I also understand about model_dir and fine_tune_checkpoint....The statement you made earlier that if the 2nd run has more steps, it will run from scratch; which is not true..When I run the model with 100 steps, a checkpoint file will be created as 'model.ckpt-100.data-00000-of-00001' in model_dir. When I run 2nd time with step=400, the training will start from 100..

Comment: and how do you know it starts from step 100?

Comment: train_config: {
  batch_size: 8
  num_steps: 200
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/tensorflow-models/research/object_detection/testing/in-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  .

Comment: In your `train_config` you have checkpoint path set to the pretrained `ssd_mobilenet` model. This is the checkpoint loaded. I did not really know that the API could start from training from another checkpoint other than the one set by `fine_tune_checkpoint`

Comment: Yes, somehow it does and that's what I am trying to find out. You can train the model for 10000 steps first and if you update the steps to 20000 and run model_main again, the model will start training from where it left.

Comment: I did not claim any problem with your config file, i just need it to see more info about your training.

Comment: Ok, i found an explanation that seemed to address this issue. It is internally handled by tensorflow rather than the tensorflow object detection api. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4116#issuecomment-387105242

Comment: Thank you danyfang for helping me out, I really appreciate your time. I already got the link you  sent when I was trying to find more info. The link talks about issue, but does not explain where and how. I know the actual loading/checking of the checkpoint happens internally in tensorflow->training->saver.py; but somehow OD module must be passing some information to core tensorflow module to check/load/save the latest checkpoint files. I wanted to know how/where that information is passed to saver.py